# Understanding the Memoryless Property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm a little confused about the memoryless property of an exponential distribution. I know for the exponential distribution we can write the memoryless property like this,

$$Pr(X > x + y | X > x) = Pr(X > y)$$

For the following, assume $X$ is the lifetime of a light bulb which is exponentially distributed with some $\lambda$.

---

My interpretation in English is the following,

*"What is the Probability of a lightbulb lasting more than $1000$ hours given it has already lasted $300$ hours".*

This is taken to be equivalent to saying,

*"What is the probability that the light bulb will last more than $700$ hours"*

---

However, for me, memorylessness would imply the following,

*"What is the probability that the light bulb will last more than $1000$ hours give it has already last $300$ hours".*

This can then be taken to mean,

*"What is the probability the light bulb will last more than $1000$ hours"*

---

To me memorylessness should just mean we drop the "$|X > x$" part, however, this clearly isn't the case. Why is that?

Secondly, how can the area under the curve between $x + y$ and $\infty$ be equal to the area under the curve from $y$ to $\infty$? I know it's something to do with the conditioning on $X > x + y$ with $X > x$, but I just don't understand how that makes the two areas equivalent.

I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: The point of the memoryless property is that it forgets the past. So if the lightbulb has already lasted 300 hours, the exponential distribution "forgets" that. If 300 hours have elapsed, then asking "what's the probability the light bulb lasts 1000 hours?" is the same as asking "what's the probability it lasts an additional 700 hours?" The exponential distribution forgets about the first 300 hours, and the answer is the same as "what's the probability a brand-new bulb lasts 700 hours?"

Comment: As for your question about the areas under curves, $P(X>y)$ is the area under the exponential density function from $y$ to $\infty$. But $P(X>x+y \mid X>x)$ is not the area under the exponential density from $x+y$ to infty. Rather it is that area *divided by* the area under the exponential density from $x$ to $\infty$ (i.e., $\frac{P(X>x+y)}{P(X>x)}$). It is a bit of a coincidence these are the same thing - that's what makes the exponential distribution special.

Comment: in short: the probability that something happen is independent of what happened before.

Comment: I think I understand it a bit more now, thanks @kccu. So you could look at it like this, 

if we take a light bulb out of a box, use it for 300 hours and then ask, "what is the probability it will last 1000 hours" is analogous to saying we take a new light bulb from the box and ask ourselves, "what is the probability of this last 700 hours"? That is, the conditioning part implies we take a new light bulb each time?

Comment: That's the right idea. It's not necessarily that we compare our 300-hour-old lightbulb to a brand new one, but rather one we have no information about (it might as well be brand new, for all we know).

Comment: @R.Evet the right idea is: the probability for lasting 1000 hours more is independent of the light bulb being new or being used over 1000 years.